# How to send a message to Activity in the side rail in Ms Teams?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

How to send a message (with link to navigate to the personal app) to Activity in the side rail to notify certain users in Teams.

[image]

Comment: Do you want user to get a notification feed, when you send a message form your app?

Comment: @Subhasish-MSFT, Yes somehow I have to push a notification to set of users to show them a new app has been added in Side rail with the link in it.

Notifications can only be sent by the specific admin users to all other corporate users.

Is there any way to implement it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question's not actually all that clear, but it *sounds* like what you're looking for could be a ["Notification Only" bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-notification-only).

Comment: I have edited the post with screenshot. Could you please cross check ones. Is there any implementation reference?

Comment: Yes, I think that's exactly what a "notification only" bot will do - see the link I provided

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by sending a proactive message form the bot once the app is installed in teams. Here is a sample code for [Proactive message in Teams](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages). When you reply to bot, add below code. It will send a notification to user in feed.

`notify.TeamsNotifyUser();`